# Lambda external function in Redshift returns 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, external

I created a Lambda function that works in the console (Invoke the SciPy package).  But doesn't return the expected results in Redshift.i

Here is the Lambda function code:

```py
import json
from scipy import stats


def binomial_test(event, context):
    t1 = event['arguments']
    # 'len(t1)' represents the number of rows in the request payload.
    # The number of results in the response payload should be the same as the number of rows received.
    resp = [None]*len(t1)

    # By default success is set to 'True'.
    success = True
    # Iterating over all rows in the request payload.
    i = 0
    for x in t1:
        p_value = stats.binomtest(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]).pvalue
        resp[i] = p_value
        i = i+1
    ret = dict()
    ret['success'] = success
    if not success:
        ret['error_msg'] = "Invalid values"
    else:
        ret['results'] = resp

    ret_json = json.dumps(ret)
    return ret_json
```

Here is the result in AWS console, so you can see that the Lambda works without issues:

```
"{\"success\": true, \"results\": [0.5381831001889082]}"
```

But in Redshift, the function just returns the value `0`.

Here is the UDF definition:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL FUNCTION stats_binom_test (BIGINT, BIGINT, NUMERIC, VARCHAR)
RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION
IMMUTABLE
LAMBDA 'stats_binom_test' 
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Can you advise how I can get the results back correctly?
I tried all kinds of data types, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

When you return `p_value` from the python function, convert them as string instead of a numeric value. I.e. When `json.dumps(ret)` converts the `ret` object as string, it does not enclose the `p_value` values with double quotes. This causes `0` result in Redshift.

Ex: You can re-write the line `resp[i] = p_value` as `resp[i] = str(p_value)`.